# My Wallpaper changes when I restart?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, desktop-background, lts

I set a custom wallpaper background simply by right clicking on the image and selecting "set as background"  but when I shut my computer off last night and turned it back on today, my desktop wallpaper was changed.  It was a default plain blue color.

Any idea why that happened?

This was the first time I shut my computer down since I installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

If the image you set as wallpaper resides in partition other than the ones that are mounted automatically when Ubuntu starts, then your wallpaper is sure to be reset as the file cannot be opened and read since it does not mount the partition on its own(may be a bug).

**Usually**, partitions other than `ext` partitions(`/`, `/home`, `/boot`, etc.) are not mounted at boot time. You may name a thousand exceptions!

To set the image as wallpaper, copy the image to your "Home" folder and then set it as your wallpaper.